# Android : Create AAR with dependentant library Projects

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aar

We are creating an SDK Project with below modules [And its dependencies are mentioned below]

- App [Android Application]
- Dev-sdk [Android Library]
- Dev-sdk1 [Android Library]
- Dev-sdk2  [Android Library]

App (build.gradle)

```
dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':Dev-sdk')
}
```

Dev-sdk (build.gradle)

```
dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':Dev-sdk1 ')
}
```

Dev-sdk1 (build.gradle)

```
dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':Dev-sdk2')
}
```

Dev-sdk2 (build.gradle)

```
dependencies {
    // No Dependencies
}
```

When I try to create aar for "Dev-sdk", It doesn't have included dependencies.

is there any way to create AAR for module Dev-sdk with all its dependencies ?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot include aar into aar. You may have to strip all the code from `Dev-sdk1` into `Dev-sdk`. Or you can upload `Dev-sdk1` to `bintray` or `maven central` and then add dependency in `Dev-sdk`'s gradle.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot add dependencies the way you desire to do in your project. `aar` don't have configuration file that state what dependencies they need. You can do one of the following:

1. Strip the code from `Dev-sdk1` into `Dev-sdk`. Since you are the developer of all of the `SDKs` you are using, this option is more appropriate for you.
2. Or try uploading `Dev-sdk1` to `Maven central repository` or `Bintray`. This way the person who will include `Dev-sdk` in his project will easily be able to add dependency for `Dev-sdk1` with something like this `compile abc.fgh.jik:version`

Answer (score 0):

The aar file **doens't contain** the transitive dependencies.
Also it doesn't have a pom file which describes the dependencies.

The alternative is to publish the library in a **maven repository** (public or private). Gradle in this case with the pom file is able to download also the dependencies.